# How to write if first child of an element isn't an a tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of links. I want to write for each link, if the first child of that link isn't an a tag... then do some code.

So far I have:

```
links.forEach((link) => {
    if(link.firstChild /* Not sure what to put here */) {
        // Do some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) property of the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correclty you want to find out whether an element is an anchor tag or not you could write your if condition like this:

```js
if (!link.firstChild.matches('a') { /* do something */ }
// OR
if (link.firstChild.tagName !== 'A') { /* do something */ }
```

However, if you're accessing `.firstChild` then you may end up with a text node due to the white space in your HTML. It might be safer to use `.firstElementChild` to avoid that being the case.